# How to prevent nginx errors due to docker boot sequence

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-swarm, supervisord

I have managed swarm using compose.yml as follows.

compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
  image: nginx

  depends_on:
    - db
    - api
  deploy:
    replicas: 2
    update_config:
    parallelism: 2
    delay: 10s


db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_DATABASE: main
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  deploy:
  placement:
  constraints: [node.role == manager]


api:
  image: node
  depends_on:
    - db
  deploy:
    replicas: 2
    update_config:
    parallelism: 2
    delay: 10s
    restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream test-web {
server web:5000 fail_timeout=5s max_fails=5;
}


proxy_pass http://test-web;
```

The problem that I am having is that the starting order of docker containers will be random as follows.

Unexpected boot results

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml blue --with-registry-auth
Creating network main_default
Creating service
Creating service main_web
Creating service main_db
Creating service main_api
```

Startup results as expected

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml blue --with-registry-auth
Creating network main_default
Creating service
Creating service main_db
Creating service main_api
Creating service main_web
```

If the web container is launched earlier than the api container, nginx encounters an error that api host is not found because web container does not know that api container exists.

So I'm investigating ways to improve this problem from the following layers.

**nginx**

is there an option to retry with nginx option even if api domain could not be found?

**docker-compose**

is there a method to reliably fix the start order of containers other than links and depends_on?

**supervisor**

To start the process in docker I am running via supervisor now.
is there a way to retry and start nginx among supervisor option even if an api container is not found and an error occurs?

Thnak you for reading my question.

Comment: Integrate wait-for-it script into your nginx image https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: @TarunLalwani amazing simply script! I'll try it. thank you

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I'm using wait for it but can't figure out the right command to run as by default nginx image doesnt expose which CMD to use.  I've tried nginx -g daemon off as shown in their code, but it ignores my template config files